# Why $\mathbf{Q}$ consists of nowhere dense singletons but its dense in $\mathbf{R}$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am struggling to understand why $\mathbf{Q}$ consists of nowhere dense singletons but it is dense in $\mathbf{R}$.

I know closure of $\mathbf{Q}$ is $\mathbf{R}$. i.e. cl($\mathbf{Q}$) = $\mathbf{R}$ so I understand $\mathbf{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbf{R}$

However $\mathbf{Q}$ is countable union of closed singletons which are nowhere dense.

Why countable union of nowhere dense singletons become dense set?

Comment: Can $\{1\}$ form sequences that get closer and closer to any point in $\Bbb R$? Can $\Bbb Q$ form sequences getting closer and closer to any point in $\Bbb R$? What is not clear is why you'd expect the closure of a union should be the union of the closures.

Comment: While it is true that a finite union of nowhere dense sets is nowhere dense, it is not always the case that an infinite union (even a countably infinite union) of nowhere dense sets is nowhere dense. Indeed, there is a name for sets that are countable unions of nowhere dense sets -- [first category sets](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstCategory.html) (also called meager sets).

Comment: "Why countable union of nowhere dense singletons become dense set?" I don't understand what you are asking here. Is that a philosophical question? Because from the mathematics point of view its just is, there's nothing more to that.

Comment: Do note that every element of $\Bbb Q$ Is a limit point. Each point’s being a closed set isn’t telling you much!

Comment: Your question seems to be based on a belief that the union of countably many nowhere dense sets **should** be nowhere dense. Do you have a basis for that belief?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably thinking of the Baire Category theorem, which states that "If a complete metric space X is written as a countable union of closed sets, then at least one of those closed sets has nonempty interior."

However, this theorem does not apply to ${\bf Q}$ because the rationals are not a complete metric space.